# Automating android: stop all system/app related interference that prevents 100% reliability?

Tags: camera, automation

A team of us at work are trying to use Pixel 4a phones to take pictures every 30sec of a remote process from 6a - 6p each day, uploading the pictures to our AWS storage container.

My colleague wrote an app which uses the [CameraX driver](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture), however our uploads keep stopping but we are not sure how to find out why. As an alternative path, I have been exploring using something "off the shelf" like [Framelapse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Nishant.Singh.DroidTimelapse&hl=en_US&gl=US) coupled with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_US&gl=US) and [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en_US&gl=US) to open Framelapse each day.

One challenge is that Android does unexpected things that thwart the ability to run this phone more like an industrial process computer. For example, I thought I'd successfully gotten Framelapse to auto-start via Tasker, and out of the blue (as in, it hadn't happened during many other attempts) I got a popup asking me if I want to rate the app. As a result, AutoInput couldn't find the button to start the recording as a result.

My questions:

- is it possible to entirely silence any behavior other than what the user has specifically done?
- if so, is there a comprehensive list of these settings?
- if not, given our goal of taking pictures every day for months without interruption, is there an alternative approach you would suggest (that uses Android phones; I realize we could start from scratch on other hardware)?

Many thanks.